# growing python process memory over time

Tags: python, memory-management

My python code process memory increases dynamically as it stores dynamic data in list, dictionary and tuples wherever necessary. Though all those dynamic data is cleared physically in their variables after then, the memory is not shooting down.

Hence i felt like there is a memory leak and i used gc.collect() method to collect all the unfreed memory. But i could not make the memory to minimum when there is no data in the variables.

Comment: Why would you expect it to go down?  What OS are you using?  In many OS's, once a process has acquired memory, the process stays that big.

Comment: i m using mac osx 10.5, i beleive in later it would eat more space.
currently it had grown around 15MB more from 24MB at initial stage.
i beleive that the process memory should grow in terms of MB which might affect the available memory size.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's very hard, in general, for a process to "give memory back to the OS" (until the process terminates and the OS gets back *all* the memory, of course) because (in most implementation) what `malloc` returns is carved out of big blocks for efficiency, but the whole block can't be given back if any part of it is still in use -- so, most C standard libraries don't even try.

For a decent discussion in a Python context, see e.g. [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t502784-python-not-giving-free-memory-back-to-the-os-gets-me-in-real-problems.html).  Evan Jones fixed some Python-specific issues as described [here](http://evanjones.ca/python-memory.html) and [here](http://evanjones.ca/python-memory-part2.html), but his patch is in the trunk since Python 2.5, so the problems you're observing are definitely with the system malloc package, not with Python per se.  A 2.6-specific explanation is [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t694873-re-python-2-6-still-not-giving-memory-back-to-the-os.html) and [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg256116.html).

A SO thread is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236001/unix-vs-windows-memory-deallocation), where Hugh Allen in his answer quotes Firefox programmers to the extend that Mac OS X is a system where it's basically **impossible** for a process to give memory back to the OS.

So, only by terminating a process can you be sure to release its memory.  For example, a long-running server, once in a while, could snapshot its state to disk and shut down (with a tiny watchdog process, system or custom, watching over it and restarting it).  If you know that the next operation will take a lot of memory for a short time, often you can `os.fork`, do the memory-hungry work in the child process, and have results (if any) returned to the parent process via a pipe as the child process terminates.  And so on, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

How big are we talking?  Python itself takes up some amount of memory.. up to maybe 30 or 40 MB I believe.  If it is bigger than that and not getting collected, you have a memory leak. Only garbage with no references can be collected, somehow your extra stuff is still referenced. Do a memory profile and see what is going on.

Comment: currently it had grown around 15MB more from 24MB at initial stage for minimal scenario. However i tried the below link tool from which i found the referred data are not more than 3MB. I could not get the remaining amount of memory details.

Comment: That isn't that big. If you are looking for a super low memory program, you normally don't code in Python. Most PCs have 2-4GB of ram, 15MB is not worth worrying about.