# quickest and cleanest method for inserting multiple rows django

Tags: python, django

I am in a situation where I would have to insert multiple records into a postgre db through an ajax call, based on a foreignkey.

Currently I am using `db1.db2_set.create(...)` for each record, looping over a list of dictionaries.

Is this the best way to do it? It seems like I'm hitting the database for every insert.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294088/accelerate-bulk-insert-using-djangos-orm

Comment: You don't hit the DB until you call `.save`. Are you doing that within the loop, or can you wait until the loop completes? If you can wait, Django will update the DB in a single transaction.

Comment: actually the create does hit the database, I dont need to call `.save()` for it to commit to the db

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that django will query database when you call save() method. So if you do something like:

```
for i in objects:
    db1.db2_set.create(i)

db1.save()
```

It may acess database only once. But still, this might be usefull:
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/766/

It's a middleware that you can add to see how many querys your django application uses in the every page you are accessing.