# Best practice of bulk_create for massive records

Tags: mysql, django, performance, orm

I use `bulk_create` to insert 1 mio records to a new table. It takes 80 seconds. Django only uses one CPU core (roughly 25% CPU, but no core is reaching 100%) I believe there is improvement potential.

Here is the code

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)

class Watchers(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, unique_for_date="date")
    num = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

batch = []
for input in inputs:
    watcher = Watcher(date=input['date'], stock=get_stock(), num=input['num'])
    batch.append(watcher)
Watcher.objects.bulk_create(batch)
```

I've tried several things:

1. Use a proper `batch_size`. The best value for me is roughly 4000. It takes 80-90 seconds.
2. Use a `ThreadPool()`. It is much slower, roughly 120-140 seconds
3. Remove the index on `DateField`. A bit slower than 1.

I'm using MySQL 5.6 community edition. Storage engine is MyISAM. Here is the config.

```
[mysqld]
server-id   = 1
default-storage-engine = MyISAM
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
datadir     = "{MYSQLDATAPATH}"
skip-external-locking
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size = 32M
max_allowed_packet = 16M

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 1024
table-open-cache               = 2048

# LOGGING
log-bin       = mysql-bin
binlog_format = mixed
```

When I import another table (similar structure, same indices, but has 9 columns), it takes 15 minutes. The time increase is not linear.

Anything wrong with bulk_create?

---

### Update 1

Although I've accept the answer, but I think I should understand the mystery. So I did some more tests and found that the Django's model creation is the root cause of slow down. When I have 800000 records, calling 800000 times create a model will be very time consuming.

The ORM framework does many internal works that we do not see, for instance the integrity check. In my case, massive records will be imported to an empty database table, so the check is not necessary.

Now I use `cursor.executemany()`, which shorten the insertion time of 800000 4-column records from 54 second to 16 second. And shorten the insertion time of 800000 13-column records from 13 minutes to 46 seconds.

According to my experiment, you'd call `executemany` for every 3000-5000 records. I tried once 800k records in one call, this is extremely slow.

Comment: Nothing wrong with bulk create but it wasn't really designed to load million records at once into the db. For that sort of task at the end of the day, nothing beats using LOAD DATA IN FILE

Comment: @e4c5 I believe `LOAD DATA IN LOCAL FILE` will be even faster. Do you want to post an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: thanks a lot. Sorry for the delay. I had actually forgotten all about the LOCAL option so answering your question was like taking a refresher course.

Comment: `key_buffer_size` should be 10-20% of _available_ RAM.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for the tip. But it seems my case does not produce too much mysql data (roughly 50MB). The real bottleneck is django's ORM. It provides the convenience for querying data, but to construct massive objects, it is not quite efficient.

Comment: Yet another argument against 3rd party packages -- they often get in the way of performance or scaling.  Sorry, I am out of _constructive_ ideas.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks and indeed I feel the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While bulk_create is useful for saving a small number of records while processing an HTML form, it's not ideally suited for saving thousands of records. As you have found out already, it's slow because it needs a lot of memory and sends a very large query to the database. Fortunatley [LOAD DATA IN FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) comes to the rescue.

> The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a
>   table at a very high speed. LOAD DATA INFILE is the complement of
>   SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE.

We can produce a file similar to what's produced by using [csv writer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) the following example is from the documentation.

```
import csv
    with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(someiterable)
```

Finally as you have already found out, the LOCAL option to LOAD DATA .. can sometimes be used for convenience.

> LOCAL works only if your server and your client both have been
>   configured to permit it

When using this option, the file does not need to be manually transferred to the server. You can generate the CSV file on the client side and the local option will cause the mysql client to automatically transfer the file to the server.

> If LOCAL is not specified, the file must be located on the server host
>   and is read directly by the server.

Comment: Finally I've got a great solution. Please see the question's "Update 1" section