# How can I avoid memory leaks with real-time plotting (matplotlib) in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, memory-leaks, jupyter-notebook

I'm training a large DQN in Jupyter notebook. I'm having some trouble finding a way to update this plot in real-time without causing a memory leak. I currently have a dirty implementation that uses ~ 1GB of RAM per episode (14,000 steps). By the time I've gotten through 7 episodes like the screenshot below, I'm about halfway out of memory on my system.

From what I've read in other posts, attempting to plot in the same thread will cause a memory leak regardless of `gc.collect()` or `del fig`, `fig.clear()`, etc. How can I update this plot within a loop without causing a memory leak?

*[I found a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516828/memory-leaks-using-matplotlib), but couldn't quite figure out how to apply it in my case with multiple figures and data that is updated dynamically.*

```py
clear_output(wait=True)
plt.close()
plt.ion()
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(10,7))
fig.tight_layout()
color = [int((item + 1) * 255 / 2) for item in p_reward_history]
axs[0].scatter(tindex, p_reward_history[-plot_len:], c=color[-plot_len:], cmap='RdYlGn', linewidth=3)
axs[0].set_title('P&L Individual Transactions')
axs[0].plot(zero_line, color="black", linewidth=3)
axs[0].set_facecolor('#2c303c')
axs[1].set_title('P&L Running Total')
axs[1].set_facecolor('#2c303c')
axs[1].plot(running_rewards_history, color="#94c273", linewidth=3)
```

*The variables that are dynamic are `running_reward_history` and `p_reward_history`. These are both lists that get new values appended to each loop.*

Current implementation looks like this:
[image]

I prefer to work in Jupyter notebook, but if I need to train in a regular shell in order to update asynchronously, that is okay with me.