# Does Matlab blocks or intercepts free() in MEX/C-code

Tags: c++, c, matlab, memory-management, mex

I have a strange situation in my MEX/C-code compiled for Matlab. I use `malloc(...)` for dynamic memory allocation and I call `free(...)` to deallocate this memory. After exiting MEX routine I can see that allocated memory is not freed at all. On the other hand if I use `mxMalloc(...)` and `mxFree(...)` everything is fine. I assume that the usage of `malloc(...)` is not prohibitory if I take care of `free(...)`. In Matlab specs I cannot find anything about intercepting or blocking basic C libraries.  Although there are some strange posts about it, like on [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/162021).

Comment: "After exiting MEX routine I can see that allocated memory is not freed at all" -- what makes you think that ?

Comment: I can see it in my System Monitor (Linux) just by looking at Matlab process. In my `MEX` code I create BIG matrices and every time I see that 100+ MB allocated for these matrices are withhold by Matlab process.

Comment: I think you'll have to show some code.  A minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You can find code here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7978-power-iteration-to-find-max-min-eigenvalue-vector and to resolve the memory issue I have replaced `free(...)` and `malloc(...)` with `mxFree(..)` and `mxMalloc()`.

Answer (score 3):

It is OK to use `malloc` and `free` (`new` and `delete[]` too), just don't neglect to call the daellocation function first if you need to return early because of an error, exception, `mexErrMsgTxt`, etc. Look at every `return`, `try`/`catch` block, and `mexErrMsg*` in your code.

If you are sure there are no bugs in your code, try `clear mex` to see if you get your memory back.

Also, I suggest to build your MEX files in a way that allows you to attach a debugger.  For example, if you are on Windows, you could follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27391300/2778484) to let you build directly in Visual Studio, which makes debugging easy (just attach to the running MATLAB.exe).

---

**UPDATE**: Addressing your comment about memory reported by `top`.  Your mex file is using a different C runtime library from whatever MathWorks used to implement it's memory management for `mxMalloc` and `mxFree`.  Note that `free` returns memory **to the runtime library, not to the operating system**. As a result, memory may be returned to the operating system at different times with different runtime libraries. From [Modern Memory Managment at ONLamp.com](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2005/10/27/memory-management.html):

> `malloc` does not normally return the freed memory to the operating system; it remains owned by the process until it terminates. The process can reuse it the next time it requests more memory, but other programs will not have access to it, even if no other memory is available. As a corollary, then, the memory footprint of a program is the size of the largest allocation(s) made at any one time.

It is notoriously difficult to reduce the size of chunks of memory allocated to a process. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236337/2778484).  The answer reiterates the point: "To return the memory to the operating system, first all the memory allocated from one of these large chunks has to be released to the runtime library. The runtime library then can, if it wants, tell the operating system to release that chunk of memory." See the other answers there too.

Thus it is not surprising that the resident set size (RSS/RES) reported by `top` does not go down right away when `free` executes.  The `malloc` used internally in MATLAB is clearly different from that used in the mex file, and may even be a custom implementation rather than a standard runtime version.

If it were an actual leak, you wouldn't get this memory back. If you pushed you system, that memory should return to the free pool. However, I would have to count this as a benefit of `mxMalloc` over `malloc`, with the disclaimer that I have not actually reproduced this effect myself.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Code exits without an error and I've introduced additional `try/catch` blocks to prevent from exiting without deallocating memory. Nothing helps, even `clear mex` doesn't solve this issue. It seems that `free(...)` doesn't work at all in this case... or is blocked by Matlab.

Comment: @VilenJumutc The Mex file is a shared library that uses a C runtime library that is independent of MATLAB. I don't think MATLAB has any way to block it. What memory metric are you looking at? What column exactly of `ps` or `top` demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I'm looking at RES column in `top`.

Comment: @VilenJumutc Freeing memory only frees memory *to the runtime library*.  It is up to the library to return it *to the OS*, where it would be observable in RES in `top`. See my update.

Comment: Thank you @chappjc for the answer. I have discovered this aftermath of `free(...)` after executing MEX calls hundred times in a row and observing that system starts to glitch starving from the lack of free memory.